# Aruba residence permit for Dutch citizens

Tags: residency, dutch-citizens, aruba

Would anyone happen to know if I can apply for a residence permit for Aruba while living outside of Aruba? I hold a Dutch passport but the application process can take months to go through.

Answer (score -2):

[The Directorate of Alien Integration, Policy and Admission (DIMAS):](https://www.dimasaruba.aw/en/registration/) has an online system through which you can make an appointment.

After [Registration](https://www.dimasaruba.aw/en/registration/), it allows you to register for an appointment for three types of services:

- Long Stay (temporary/permanent)
- Short Stay (and other products)
- Information and Helpdesk

The appointment calendar shows time slots available 60  to 90 days in advance, so you should be able to register and make the request prior to arrival.

```
DIMAS
Paardenbaaistraat # 11
Oranjestad, Aruba
Tel: +(297) 522 1500
Fax: +(297) 522 1505
E-mail: dimas@aruba.gov.aw
Website: www.dimasaruba.com
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The linked source is for those applying in Aruba; the question is about applying elsewhere.